# Files uploaded to SoundCloud by API are downloaded with name 'SoundCloud Download' instead of original file name

Tags: api, soundcloud

We are constantly uploading audio to SoundlCloud from our site by API and today i've noticed that when i download track from an account interface it is saving as ***'SoundCloud Download'***, even no extension.

I've checked other files uploaded and is looks like it started to happen around 2 weeks ago, because files older than 2 weeks are downloaded with their original file name. I've double checked that our upload solution didn't change and even implemented another one, but results were the same.

To me it looks like something has changed on their side. Does anyone experience same problem? Any ideas where to look at?

One of the solutions i'm using to test this is as follows:

```
$client = new \Njasm\Soundcloud\SoundcloudFacade(
    '...',
    '...'
);
$client->userCredentials('...', '...');
$filename = str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES['file_data']['name']);
$pathName = sys_get_temp_dir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_data']['tmp_name'], $pathName);

$trackData = [
    'title' => $_POST['title'],
    'downloadable' => true,
    'license' => 'cc-by-nc-sa',
    'sharing' => 'private'
];
$track = $client->upload($pathName, $trackData);
```

it is an API Wrapper in PHP - https://github.com/njasm/soundcloud

Thanks.

Comment: Hi I have the same issue. I'm using https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python